# Make pipeline fail when npm audit detects dependencies

Tags: javascript, npm, dependencies, audit

I am using npm audit on my gitlab CI, everything works fine I have a json created with the list of the dependencies to update.
Now, I want this pipeline to fail everytime a dependency is outdated.
On other languages we have php/pip that makes the pipeline fail
Any idea ?

```
  image: "registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/security-products/analyzers/npm-audit:1.4.0"
  stage: security-check
  variables:
    TOOL: npm
  script:
    - /analyzer run
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dependency_scanning: gl-dependency-scanning-report.json
    paths:
      - gl-dependency-scanning-report.json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the option for allowing failures or not with the `allow_failure` option in your job.

You can add this to your security-check job with the following:

```
  image: "registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/security-products/analyzers/npm-audit:1.4.0"
  stage: security-check
  variables:
    TOOL: npm
  allow_failure: false
  script:
    - /analyzer run
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dependency_scanning: gl-dependency-scanning-report.json
    paths:
      - gl-dependency-scanning-report.json
```

There is also another tool [here](https://gitlab.com/jitesoft/open-source/javascript/audit-for-gitlab)

This tool offers environment variables that can be configured depending on the severity of the npm audit.

From the above Gitlabs Readme:

SCAN_EXIT_CODE - Will force a specific exit code in case of a moderate, high or critical vulnerability is found.
In case this is not set, exit code 1 will be used in the cases above, else 0.